# Having troubles renaming a file in the RubyMine "Jetbrains" IDE

Tags: ruby, rename, rubymine

It's a great environment, but when I right click on, say a model .rb file, it is not readily apparent how I might rename a file.

Now RubyMine JetBrains is a brilliant program which I love, so I'm not going to stop using it,  I just need to get around this simple problem.

Comment: brilliant and retarded at the same time imo. up to this day, i still dont know how to rename the file WITHOUT refactoring on rubymine

Comment: Remember that time when you could rename a file/folder using RubyMine and uncheck the "search for references" to skip the not-so-great refactoring system? Ah... I remember... Good ol'days

Comment: RubyMine has turned into a pile of garbage bloatware... you actually cannot rename a file if it doesn't have a file extension

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `Alt+Shift+R` shortcut to rename the file when it's highlighted in the project view panel.

Generally, actions like `rename` is part of the [`Refactoring`](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201485672) (because you also need to rename the usages of it) so you will also find it in the `Refactor` menu on top.

Comment: `Alt+Shift+R` is dead to me :-(  Is there an updated shortcut?  I can't see anything in the keymap.  UPDATE: Doh! unselect 'search for references'.

Answer (score 0):

In RubyMine 2018.3 on Windows use:

**Shift+F6**

or

Right click on the file name and choose Refactor > Rename